# result set from mysql view does not match

Tags: java, php, mysql

We have tried both PHP and Java code to run a MySQL data view. The result set does not match the data that is in the view.

The query is

```
SELECT * FROM xxxx_v WHERE id = 19
```

In the view we have the following result: 19, 3120, 1618, 1502

In the PHP and/or Java result set we get: 19, 3121, 1624, 1497

How can the numbers be different?

Comment: Show the data in your table and the php and java code.

Comment: Hi Jens, I am not very good at using this site and have had problems posting the data view table. The data is as I have it above. the columns are user_id, t_count, hits, misses. As you can see the data returned back is different.

Comment: It can't be different. Fortunately the same request is supposed to return the same results, whatever the caller is ! The single thing which can lead to different results is subtle request difference, for example when handling types like Dates : imagine if your RDBMS client pass it as "DMY" and your code "MDY", etc. But it doesn't seem to be possible for a query like yours. Provide us full code / query / data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check that your getting the data from the correct place?

I don't see how you could be getting data different to what is there, so I would suggest perhaps trying an INSERT statement in the PHP and see if it affects the database your looking at. If it doesn't, then you know you're looking at the wrong one.

An INSERT statement would go along the lines of...

```
INSERT INTO xxxx_v (user_id, t_count, hits, misses) ("1", "2", "3", "4")
```